# What happens when I blink a Manic Scribe multiple times?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

If I have a [Manic Scribe](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bManic%20Scribe%5d) and 2 [Momentary Blink](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bMomentary%20Blink%5d)s, is it possible to use [Momentary Blink](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bMomentary%20Blink%5d) on [Manic Scribe](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bManic%20Scribe%5d) multiple times, and if so, does his ability trigger again?

Comment: Welcome to Board & Card Games Stack Exchange! Could you please take a few moments to improve the grammar and spelling of your post? Right now, it's a bit unclear what you are asking.

Answer (score 5):

What you are describing is possible, but I will go over various interpretations of what you described. We will assume that you already have a Manic Scribe on the battlefield.

The most likely way you will accomplish what you're trying to do is by casting Momentary Blink on the scribe, letting the spell resolve so it can come back and trigger its "enters the battlefield" ability, and then casting your second Momentary Blink on it. This will cause it to leave and re-enter twice, triggering its ability twice, and overall making each opponent put 6 cards in their graveyard.

You could also cast Momentary Blink on it, then hold priority and cast the second Momentary Blink on it before the first one resolves. This is a Bad Idea, because after one of them resolves, the other will not have a valid target and be countered (fizzle) on resolution (as the scribe left the battlefield and came back, so is a new object). Then, you wasted one of your blinks! Your opponent will only put 3 cards into their graveyard, because Manic Scribe only entered the battlefield once.

Manic Scribe has a triggered ability that triggers on your opponent's upkeep (if you have Delirium) in addition to the one that triggers when it enters the battlefield, however you cannot cause this trigger to repeat in the same way. Your opponent's upkeep happens and the trigger is put on the stack. At this point, if you blink the scribe, it will leave and re-enter, and the "enters the battlefield" trigger will go on the stack too, but there is no way to get a second "beginning of upkeep" trigger to occur.

Answer (score 0):

You can cast any amount of momentary blinks on your scribe, after the blink brings it back onto the battlefield both  you and your opponent  can target the scribe again as normal. Each time the scribe comes back its "enters the battlefield" ability will trigger again.

Comment: One thing to watch out for is to make sure each blink resolves before casting the next one. If you cast two in a row, the second one to resolve will fizzle because the returning scribe is actually a new instance, and not the same one you targeted when you cast the spell!

Comment: Thank you. I am working on a deck that reactivates annoying effects. Creatures such as reflector mage, manic scribe, subjegator angel, and a few others, because I can't afford $70 mythic kill all cards

Comment: I know its a strange style of play, but I think if I do it right, the results could be impressive.